# What does (1-) mean in the context of probability mass functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am checking over some work I'm doing, and I noticed the following formula:

$P(X=i) $

$= P(X\le i) - P(X < i)$

$ = F(1) - F(1^-)$

I understand the concept of the second line, but I don't understand the 3rd line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F(1^-)$ is shorthand for
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}F(x)
$$
which is to say, the limit of $F(x)$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from below.

Comment: Honestly, if you know what the second line means, and what $F(1)$ means, then in my opinion it shouldn't be too hard to guess what $F(1^-)$ means from the context. True, guessing is not the same as knowing, but you can get pretty far that way most of the time.